# Closing Framework7 picker by click on active picker element

Tags: javascript, android, html, picker, html-framework-7

I'm using Framework7 for creating HTML5 Android app and want to write function for click(or touch) event for active picker element like that:

```
$$(document).on('click', '.picker-selected', function (e) { 
  myPicker.close();
});
```

It works well if I try it in a browser on my computer. But on smartphone it doesn't work.

I guess that this is due to the fact that the touchstart and touchend events conflict with the click event. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For any modal, close it using `myApp.closeModal()`

[link to documentation](https://framework7.io/docs/modal.html#close-modals-with-javascript)

Comment: Close the modal is not a problem. The task is to close the window when the element with the active index was clicked(touched, tapped, etc.).

Comment: What you mean exactly by "close the window" ?

Comment: Same as closing the picker. I open picker, then I need to close it:)